# Add cursor:hand with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cursor, addition

How can I add the style property `cursor` in a td element with JavaScript?

I've tried this:

```
var tabla = document.getElementById("table");
var fila  = document.createElement("tr");
var celda1 = document.createElement("td");
var estilo = document.createElement('style');

//I check the navigator
var gko = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (gko.indexOf('gecko') != -1)
{
// All the rest navigators
estilo.innerHTML = "td {cursor: pointer;}";
} 
else
{
//IE navigator
estilo.innerHTML = "td {cursor: hand;}";
}

fila.appendChild(celda1);
tabla.appendChild(fila);
```

This works for all navigators except Internet Explorer 9.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cursor: hand` won't work in IE9 because `cursor: pointer` is the right way to do it. If you need to support IE5, just include both in your CSS file and get rid of your JavaScript:

```
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
```

Otherwise, `cursor: pointer;` will suffice. In either case, you don't really need JavaScript for this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought cursor:hand was the right systax for all versions of IE, but works fine with cursor:pointer. Thanks again.